# How to Rank By Partition with island and gap issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Is it possible to rank item by partition without use CTE method

Expected Table

| item | value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| A | 20 | 1 |
| B | 30 | 2 |
| B | 40 | 2 |
| C | 50 | 3 |
| C | 60 | 3 |
| A | 70 | 4 |
| A | 80 | 4 |

By giving id to the partition to allow agitated function to work the way I want.

| item | MIN | MAX | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 | 1 |
| B | 30 | 40 | 2 |
| C | 50 | 60 | 3 |
| A | 70 | 80 | 4 |

SQL Version: Microsoft SQL Sever 2017

Comment: Sorry , it is suppose to be 1,2,3,4

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a CTE?  Which version of SQL Server are you using?  And, does your initial data set have a column you can actually sort by *(SQL datasets are unordered unless you can enforce an order with `ORDER BY`, such as with an id column, a timestamp column, etc.)*?

Comment: I want to code to be simple to be understand for other people in my team that why i avoid using CTE method. The data set is order by datetime.

Comment: CTEs make code easier to understand, don't avoid them for that reason.  If your data has a datetime column, include that in your question's example source data.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple query like `SELECT 
    item,
    MIN(value) AS "min",
    MAX(value) AS "max",
    id
FROM t
GROUP BY item, id`?

Comment: @Alexey - I think the OP's question is misleading, I think they want to derive the `id` column, they don't start with it.  So, they haven't actually shown a real representative source data example.

Comment: Ok thank you. Will do for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `value` column provides the intended ordering of the records which we see in your question above, we can try using the difference in row numbers method here.  Your problem is a type of gaps and islands problem.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY value) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT item, MIN(value) AS [MIN], MAX(value) AS [MAX], MIN(ID) AS ID
FROM cte
GROUP BY item, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(value);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

If you don't want to use a CTE here, for whatever reason, you may simply inline the SQL code in the CTE into the bottom query, as a subquery:

```sql
SELECT item, MIN(value) AS [MIN], MAX(value) AS [MAX], MIN(ID) AS ID
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY value) rn2
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY item, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(value);
```

Comment: @MatBailie 1) CTEs are not "methods," 2) the CTE in my answer can easily be inlined to the query on the bottom as a subquery.  This is a trivial change to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate group IDs by analyzing the previous row `item` value that could be obtained with the `LAG` function and finally use `GROUP BY` to get the minimum and maximum `value` in item groups.

```
SELECT
    item,
    MIN(value) AS "min",
    MAX(value) AS "max",
    group_id + 1 AS id
FROM (    
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN item = prev_item THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY value) AS group_id
    FROM (    
        SELECT 
            *,
            LAG(item, 1, item) OVER (ORDER BY value) AS prev_item
        FROM t
    ) items
) groups   
GROUP BY item, group_id
```

Query produces output

| item | min | max | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 | 1 |
| B | 30 | 40 | 2 |
| C | 50 | 60 | 3 |
| A | 70 | 80 | 4 |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6bc127f651679a0d6304e611361b8a6)

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me some time to understand the sum part.